# datagrid to be validated for null value

Tags: c#

Friends
I had a datagridview in my windowsdesktop application to insert data into the database. when i click the  add button validation should be done to ensure that no cells are left empty .I am not using cellvalidatorevent since i think its complicating process
i had written code like this

```
public void validateDatagrid()
        {
            if (tblpurchaserequest.RowCount == 1)
            {
                lblstatus.Text = "There is No  Purchase Data to Add";

            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tblpurchaserequest.RowCount; i++)
                {



                    if (tblpurchaserequest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "" || tblpurchaserequest.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == null)
                    {
                        lblstatus.Text = "Please Enter Item in " + i + "th ROW";
                    }

                    if (tblpurchaserequest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "" || tblpurchaserequest.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == null)
                    {
                        lblstatus.Text = "Please Enter Description in " + i + "th ROW";
                    }
                    if (tblpurchaserequest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "" || tblpurchaserequest.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value == null)
                    {
                        lblstatus.Text = "Please Enter Supplier in " + i + "th ROW";
                    }
                    if (tblpurchaserequest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "" || tblpurchaserequest.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == null)
                    {
                        lblstatus.Text = "Please EnterQuantity in " + i + "th ROW";
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

but this is giving exception 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
pls advice me my mistake

Comment: Can't you use a debugger to find the source of your problem? (One of your object's properties is call while the object is set to null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously some value is null and the way you do the check in your if clause would need to be in a different order.

Change from:

```
if (tblpurchaserequest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "" 
    || tblpurchaserequest.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == null)
```

to:

```
if (tblpurchaserequest.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == null
    || tblpurchaserequest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "")
```

That is, check for NULL first. This will ensure that the second part in your if does not get evaluated, if the first part indeed returns a null (which is giving you an "object reference blah blah" error)

You will need to reverse the order on all if statements in your code block.

Answer (score 0):

Write a method for example:

```
    private void CallingMethod()
    {
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        if (IsNullOrEmpty(dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value)
        {
           lblValue.Text = "Please enter a value for this cell";
        }

    }

    // Method to check if the cell is empty
    public bool IsNullOrEmpty(object cellValue)
    {
        if (cellValue == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
          if (cellValue.ToString().Trim() == "")
          {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This should simplify your code and make it easier to read and understand.

The reason for the object reference error is because if you use .ToString() on a object with a null value it would throw an exception. My advice is to first check if the value is null and if not then test if it is eqaul to an empty string.